# JSF not being rendered

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I've got a tiny webapp with *index.jsp* that forwards (it mostly only contains):

```
<jsp:forward page="/pages/inputname.jsf" />
```

*web.xml* contains (in addition to everything else you'd expect; see more below):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*inputname.jsp* isn't rendering (here's the URI):

```
http://localhost:8080/simpleWeb/index.jsp
```

The page appears thus in the browser (label, input edit field, button):

```
#{msg.prompt} #{personBean.personName} #{msg.button_text}
```

I'm guessing this is because it's not getting through the Faces servlet. However, I'm uncertain of how to force it through. (Note that I'm elsewhere, with RichFaces and MyFaces, having similar trouble with *.xhtml* files too, but I'd like to get this simpler case solved first.)

The tutorial has me using these libraries (via Maven), in WEB-INF/lib/:

```
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
jsf-api-1.2_02.jar
jsf-impl-1.2-b19.jar
jstl-1.1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.12.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
servlet-api-2.3.jar
standard-1.1.2.jar
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*web.xml* (yes, it has the DOCTYPE web-app header):

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. The `index.jsp` needs to be called as `index.jsf` by browser.
2. The `index.jsp` should fire a redirect rather than forward. JSTL `<c:redirect>` may be useful.

Regardless, such an `index.jsp` is pretty pointless. Just add `/pages/inputname.jsf` as `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml` and provide a **blank** `/pages/inputname.jsf` file next to the *real* `/pages/inputname.jsp` to fool the server that the file exist (otherwise it will go 404).

As to the `web.xml`, the `DOCTYPE` doesn't belong there. It's an ancient remnant of Servlet 2.3 approach and before (almost a decade old already). On Servlet 2.4 and newer, there are XSD's. Even more, since you're using JSF 1.2, the `web.xml` should be declared as **at least** Servlet 2.4, preferably higher, the highest your container can support, so that you can utilize the newest available API facilities. Tomcat 5.5 is Servlet 2.4, Tomcat 6.0 is Servlet 2.5 and Tomcat 7.0 is Servlet 3.0.

#### See also:

- [JSF 1.2 tutorial with Eclipse and Tomcat](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/01/jsf-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-tomcat.html)

Comment: I've made the changes you state here (in paragraphs 2, welcome-file, and 3, web-app tag and 2.5), but the behavior remains the same: no JSF rendering occurs. I've written a number of JSF-based apps with no trouble. This one is from a tutorial that proposes to help me make the leap to using Maven which I've been putting off. Basically, I want to feel more at home knowing how to choose any suite of JARs for JSF (and, actually, Facelets) work and that I can always overcome problems such as this because I grok how it works rather than being able to follow some tutorial's imposing of a certain set.

Comment: Does the URL in address bar match `*.jsf`? What do you see in generated HTML source? Are JSF tags parsed or not? Do you see anything sensible in server logs? What servletcontainer are you using? Having the `servlet-api-2.3.jar` in the classpath is also not a good sign. I don't do Maven, but I'm certain that you must be able to choose a specific servlet API version. Choose the max one which your container supports.

Comment: Tomcat 6. I've variously tried "h t t p :// localhost:8080/simpleWeb/" (because of the welcom-file entry) and "h t t p :// localhost:8080/simpleWeb/pages/inputname.jsf". Both produce the same output and, in the generated page source, it's obvious that no JSF replacement was done either from the properties file or the backing bean. Yeah, as for choosing the JAR stack, I'm at the mercy of the tutorial. This is not the set of JARs I use when I'm serious about doing JSF.

Comment: And the server logs? Well, given the symptoms as far it look like that your environment is still at Servlet 2.3 modus somehow. I am no Maven guy, so I may be completely wrong, but I think that the following link is useful for you: http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2009/11/25/creating-a-jsf-application-in-10-minutes/ It covers Servlet 2.5 and JSF 1.2, exactly what you need.

Comment: And, as I say, I'm more interested in understanding how to sort out issues like this than solving this example, which is only a tutorial. So, what JAR, what web.xml setting, where do tags fit in, etc. I need to sit next to a JSF/Facelet guru for a day--hard to find any around here and, for a couple of years now, I've wanted to become that guy for others around me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that link. If I can solve the problem, I'll come back and say what and how, then click your answer.

Comment: OK, when leaving Maven outside consideration: 1) ensure that your web.xml conforms servlet 2.5 (you can find an example of the correct declaration [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) ). 2) Get rid of all JAR's expect of `jsf*.jar`, `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` (the remnant are not necessary for a minimal JSF config and the `servlet-api-2.3.jar` would only collide because Tomcat by itself already ships with Servlet 2.5).

Comment: Sadly, Neeraj Verma's Maven tutorial works worse than the one I was following. On the first, I note that it didn't ask for JARs like Avalon; that must come in as an errant dependency. I think I'm going to have to return to what I know that's tried and true. I'll have to figure out how to get that (and only that) via Maven <dependencies />. I understand the Maven approach to setting up a web app (and it's ugly as compared to the normal Eclipse webapp set-up). Unfortunately, the Maven examples are written by people who don't know how to write JSF or are too careless to finish the job completely.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar, this is what is used for redirect:

```
<body>
    <%
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsf");
    %>
</body>
```

trying to put "/index.jsp" in the browser brings you to "/index.jsf".

Comment: Please, don't recommend scriptlets to the noobs.

Comment: Thanks: yeah, the point was never the index.jsp -> inputname.jsp (jsf) in the first place. I was only being faithful to the tutorial since in all fairness you shouldn't indict a tutorial unless and until you've done all the (even stupid) stuff it does. No, here the trouble is forcing the JSF in inputname.jsp to render.