# Helloworld JSF2.0 Page is not rendering as html tags

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Im a Totally new in Java and JSF. I'm using eclipse Indigo and Tomcat 6.0.3 and JSF 2.0.

When i run the Page in Browser, I just get an empty page, but i could the elements in firebug that it is still in JSF tags itself. It is not rendering in html..

This is my web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/AddUser.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

I have Tried to add the `url-pattern` as `*.xhtml` but it still doesnt work.

This is my xhtml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
        <title>Add New User Form</title>
</h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
             <h:form>
                     <h:outputText value="Age"></h:outputText>
                 </h:form>
            </f.view>
      </h:body>
```

Comment: can you provide the code for xhtml file? and beside this question already exist. check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207616/jsf-tags-not-being-rendered-as-html or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764204/jsf-tags-not-rendering-facesservlet-not-working-maybe and maybe this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866597/jsf-not-being-rendered

Comment: I have tried most of the things what is mentioned on those pages, it dint work out, so that i created a new page for this...

Comment: What is the full url you write in the browser?

Comment: In what URL format are you accessing the pages?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ContactFormJSF  There is some html element and that alone can been seen but not jsf elements...

Comment: try localhost:8080/app/ContactFormJSF. It depend on the `<url-pattern>` you configured in your web.xml. You URL should match the patterns so that the `Faces Servlet` can handle your request.

Comment: please check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865344/jsf-2-0-not-rendering-any-page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pattern of the JSF servlet is `<url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>`. Change the pattern to `*.jsf` and access `http://localhost:8080/yourXhtmlFileName.jsf`.

Comment: This is job of the default suffix - `<param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>`. JSF will automatically translate the jsf extension to xhtml.

Comment: Yes as the DEFAULT_SUFFIX is already mentioned in my Web.XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try localhost:8080/app/ContactFormJSF. It depend on the `<url-pattern>` you configured in your web.xml. You URL should match the pattern so that the Faces Servlet can handle your request and render the page.

Comment: It doesnt work out,i get 404 if change the url to localhost:8080/app/ContactFormJSF.

Comment: What is the root path of your application? Try to add the root path.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance in missing libraries under `WEB-INF/lib` folder..

In Most of the cases the required jars will not configured properly

- Ensure that your jars are are under `WEB-INF/lib` directory

Comment: I have all the jars of jsf inside WEB-INF/lib namely jsf-impl.jar,    jsf-api.jar, jstl.jar,   commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar,   commons-chain-1.1.jar,    commons-collections.jar,   commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,   commons-‌​digester-1.8.jar. should i add any other than this??

Comment: Yesterday you was helping me out i think so, I solved that 404 error by the changing just the folder structure and the url psttarn in web.xml... Thanks for that...

Comment: welcome..Did you get any console error in `eclipse`, If you get post them

Answer (score 0):

Did you use following tag on your web.xml file ?

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>//you are missing "faces"
</welcome-file-list>
```

Full xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**Updated**

The element type `f:view` must be terminated by the matching end-tag `</f:view>`.

```
   <f:view>
         <h:form>
                 <h:outputText value="Age"></h:outputText>
         </h:form>
   </f.view>   //Here it should be </f:view>
```

You are using `.` you should use `:`. Following is the corrected format :

```
   <f:view>
         <h:form>
                 <h:outputText value="Age"></h:outputText>
         </h:form>
   </f:view>
```

Comment: Pls check my above Web.XML, I have mentioned all the elements which you are saying...

Comment: I think you are missing `faces`...ues and try... And can you paste my code and try?Pls..   And also use url `localhost:8080/yourProjectName`

Comment: @Khirthan See my updated answer. you are missing `:` in tag `</f:view`

Comment: Iam Sorry, it is right in my code only, just here only it is wrong.. In my code it is </f:view> only... All the basic tags like <head>,<body> is still rendered only as "<h:head>", "<b:body>"...